Risks of not repairing a slightly dripping downpipe in the cellar?
When I flush the toilet on the upper floor, water runs out slightly in the pipe in the basement (right at the opening where it is rusty. The opening is actually meant for cleaning the pipe).
I got quotes and they have to replace the whole pipe in the basement (1300$).
What are the risks of not repairing a slightly dripping downpipe in the cellar? Simply lay cloths etc. on the floor




A small leak now usually has the bad habit of becoming a big leak later on.  Unless the whole pipe is bad/rusting, I do not see right now why some cutting, a couple of couplings and new section will not work.  Maybe get some more quotes.

That is a waste water pipe? In what locale? it seems to have other, small pipes feeding in to it at odd angles.

Yes, that's right, waste water pipe. In the cellar. There is also a branch from the washing machine and water tap in the cellar.

Can we get a wider shot?
